# Sequential animation with jquery children

Tags: jquery, animation

I am appending a html string (var data['return']) to a ul element $('#sidebar_append') which has the following form

```
<li>item one</li>
<li>item two</li>
<li>item three</li>
```

I want to create a sequential fadeIn animation for all the children. I've tried the following, but it would not fadeIn

```
$('#sidebar_append')
    .hide()
    .append(data['return'])
    .children()
    .each(function() {
          $(this).fadeIn('fast')
    });
```

It's weird as when I do a *console.log($(this))* I actually get the `li` in firebug but no `fadeIn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it's pretty simple, I forgot that `$('#sidebar_append')` is still hidden. You also need a delay to create a sequence animation:

```
$('#sidebar_append')
  .append(data['return'])
  .children().hide()
  .each(function(index) {
      $(this).delay(150*index).fadeIn('slow')
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(function(){
    $('#sidebar_append').append(data['return']).children().hide();
    var index=0;
    function show()
    {
        $('#sidebar_append li').eq(index).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            index+=1;
            if($('#sidebar_append li').eq(index).length) show();
            else return false;
        });
    }
    show();
})();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vCAMy/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Together with that plugin [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/) the whole thing gets much shorter:

```
$('#sidebar_append').append(data['return'])
    .children().hide().each($).fadeIn('fast',$);
```

voilà